# EF classes vs L2S classes

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

According to this article:

http://dotnetanonymous.blogspot.com/2010/03/entity-framework.html

There are some L2S classes that have the name "Entity" in them, but actually do not belong to EF.  Which classes are these?

Comment: does it matter? L2S and EF are two seperate and different technologies.

Comment: Well, I just don't want to be confused by them, since I'm studying EF4.

Answer (score 2):

[System.Data.Linq.EntityRef and System.Data.Linq.EntitySet.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.aspx)

Comment: You mean [`EntitySet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341748.aspx), right? As [`EntitySet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.entityset.aspx) is an EF class. Confusing? Indeed.

Comment: @Allon, click the link in my answer.

Comment: @Craig, I know that the link points to the right namespace, but you still wrote the wrong class name.

Comment: @Allon, are you complaining that I left off the type parameter? Surely anyone who clicks the link will get the point, right?

Comment: @Craig: What I'm saying is, that `EntitySet<T>` is a L2S class, and that `EntitySet` is a EF class. In a question asking to differentiate between L2S and EF, I believe it is _especially_ important to be precise. If the question was about only L2S or only EF, then context would have disambiguated, but this is not the case. Surly anyone who doesn't click link should also get the correct answer, right?

Comment: @Allon, no, `EntitySet<T>` does not disambiguate the two, because there are other `EntitySet<T>`, just as there are other `EntitySet` types. The link, plus reading the one-sentence answer, OTOH, makes it clear. In the interests of pleasing your pedantry, however, I'll introduce some redundancy into that sentence.